# How to configure Amazon ELB ping target for haproxy

Tags: haproxy, amazon-elb

I'm trying to setup Amazon ELB to route requests to couple of haproxy servers. ELB requires a ping target to the respective servers for health check. It uses index.html at port 80. I'm struggling to configure an index.html in haproxy. Here's my haproxy configuration :

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    mode        http
    option      dontlognull
    option      httpclose
    option      httplog
    option      forwardfor
    option      redispatch
    option httpchk HEAD /index.html HTTP/1.0
    timeout connect 10000 # default 10 second time out if a backend is not found
    timeout client 300000
    timeout server 300000
    maxconn     60000
    retries     3

#
# Host HA-Proxy's web stats on Port 81.
listen stats :1936
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /
    stats auth Username:Password

frontend  main *:80
    log 127.0.0.1 local2
    capture request  header         X-Forwarded-For      len 500
    capture response header         X-Query-Result       len 100
    acl url_webapp                  path_beg -i /supporttoolbar
    acl url_jsonproxy               path_beg -i /proxy

backend webapp
    balance     roundrobin
    server      webapp1 10.100.86.xxx:80 check
backend jsonproxy
    balance     roundrobin
    server      webapp1 10.100.86.xxx:80 check
```

The html page is located under **/var/www/html/**

I tried adding **option httpchk HEAD /index.html HTTP/1.0** under **defaults** section, but didn't work.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to check if the servers behind haproxy are actually alive? If the heartbeat doesn't reach behind the haproxy instance than the entire check should fail. At least, that's what I think...

Comment: @NathanC The servers are alive, I can route the requests using their IP directly. Only problem is the index html page is not reachable.That's why I'm wondering there's something missing in the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nateware/3987720). It basically describes/configures what you require:

```
# Create a monitorable URI which returns a 200 if at least 1 server is up.
# This could be used by Traverse/Nagios to detect if a whole server set is down.
acl servers_down nbsrv(servers) lt 1
monitor-uri /haproxy?monitor
monitor fail if
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternate by adding the following entry in the Haproxy configuration file.

```
defaults
    mode        http
    option      dontlognull
    option      httpclose
    option      httplog
    option      forwardfor
    option      redispatch
    timeout connect 10000 # default 10 second time out if a backend is not found
    timeout client 300000
    timeout server 300000
    monitor-uri /index.html
    maxconn     60000
    retries     3
```

The entry **monitor-uri /index.html** entry did the trick. Haproxy has this built-in health check which returns a 200 if the service is up. I just mocked it to use /index.html which Amazon ELB recognizes.

Comment: where is i`ndex.html` located?